# Aid with getting OpenAL Audio Libraries on Eclipse Mac

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, audio

I have scoured the internet for help with this one. I don't typically enjoy using stack exchange because a lot of people can sometimes start fights on here, so please just bear with me. I am currently learning the C++ language, and I'm only about 2-ish weeks in. I am working with a team of new programmers, and to learn the language, we are creating a tiny text based game. We want to have the game play audio at different times, and from my hours of research, I have determined, that for cross platform audio, I want OpenAL.

The problem is: How do I use OpenAL with Eclipse and Mac? I haven't found any guides for this online, and the only OpenAL libraries I can find are all .exe files, which I can't use on mac. I also cannot find a ton of tutorials on using the OpenAL audio libraries, so if you could point me at one of those, that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance! Cheers!

Comment: In Xcode you can add `-framework OpenAL` to your Other Library flags to import OpenAL. Then in your C++ program just do `#include <OpenAL/OpenAL.h>`. Now you can use OpenAL just like you do for iOS, Windows, Linux, etc..

Comment: @Brandon yes, however, i am using Eclipse, not xcode.

Comment: The only difference is that you have to manually specify the paths. `-I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/Versions/A/Headers` `-L/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries -framework OpenAL`     `#include <al.h>`   Otherwise download OpenAL from the source and build it then link to it.

Comment: @Brandon okay, so where do i get the libraries? i can only seem to find installers for windows computers.

Comment: @Brandon those only give me .exe's. am i missing something?

Comment: https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft  http://ingar.satgnu.net/devenv/mingw32/local.html#openalsoft http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34546/where-can-i-get-the-openal-sdk-for-c

Comment: Okay you're loosing me

Comment: OpenAL is packaged as a Framework and part of the platform SDK on MacOSX (you should be using this rather than libraries and headers in `/usr`.  You shouldn't need to install it. @Brandon's comments above look plausible if you find which of the squillions of possible places in the Eclipse CDT UI in which you can put header search paths and library folders is the correct one. 

It has to be said, you're making life really hard for yourself using Eclipse CDT for MacOSX development. The lack of help on this subject is because developers generally don't do it.

Comment: @marko okay, i get it. ill probably migrate to xcode. the thing is, im not developing for mac specifically, im working to be cross platform. we have a whole team to work on both windows and osx.

Comment: Eclipse will be a substandard experience on Windows as well.   If you're concerned about project file management, consider using cmake - it can generate both Visual Studio and Xcode project files from a common project definition and deals with many of the common platform differences.